# How to create permanent files on Heroku?

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, pickle, dyno

I have a telegram bot with a Postgres DB hosted on Heroku Free dyno. In one stage of my code, I want to save pickled files permanently so that I can access them later. Storing it on a table doesn't feel like a nice idea as it is a nested class with a variable number of inputs.
Problem is that Heroku deletes these files frequently or at least on each restart or push. Is there any way to tackle this problem?

Comment: It may be useful to learn a bit more about the philosophy heroku uses for building web apps (12 Factor apps): https://12factor.net/ (Heroku manages this page)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use external services such as AWS S3, GCP Cloud Storage (Buckets), Azure Blob Storage etc.. for that. Or you may consider using an addon such as [Felix Cloud Storage](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/felix), [Cloud Cube](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/cloudcube), [Bucketeer](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/bucketeer), [HDrive](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/hdrive) for easy integration.

Here is what the [documentation states](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted):

> The Heroku filesystem is ephemeral - that means that any changes to
> the filesystem whilst the dyno is running only last until that dyno is
> shut down or restarted. Each dyno boots with a clean copy of the
> filesystem from the most recent deploy. This is similar to how many
> container based systems, such as Docker, operate.
>
> In addition, under normal operations dynos will restart every day in a
> process known as "Cycling".
>
> These two facts mean that the filesystem on Heroku is not suitable for
> persistent storage of data. In cases where you need to store data we
> recommend using a database addon such as Postgres (for data) or a
> dedicated file storage service such as AWS S3 (for static files). If
> you don't want to set up an account with AWS to create an S3 bucket we
> also have addons here that handle storage and processing of static
> assets https://elements.heroku.com/addons